# c++ external class interface and templates

Tags: c++, namespaces

In C++ we can omit namespace qualification in case of using function that takes, as its first argument, object of type declared in the same namespace as our function. However, I've noticed that this doesn't work with templated functions (like *std::get*). I wrote simple example to confirm that this is really related to templates:

```
namespace ns {

    struct S {};

    void sFoo(const S&) {}
    template<typename T> void sBar(const S&) {}
}

void foo()
{
    ns::S s;
    sFoo(s); // ok
    sBar<int>(s); // error: ‘sBar’ was not declared in this scope
    ns::sBar<int>(s); // ok
}
```

I tried explicit instantiation, but it didn't change anything (even if it would, it would be worse option than just using *using*).

So why exacly can't I call templated function without specifying its namespace (and assuming neither *using* nor *using namespace* directives)?

Answer (score 2):

`sBar` is not a function, but a *function template*. The argument-dependent lookup only works for *function* names. It's true that `sBar<int>` is a function, but you can't instantiate the template if you don't know its proper name!

Unrelatedly, if the template argument can be deduced, that ADL does work:

```
namespace ns
{
    template <typename T> void sZip(T &) { }
}

void foo()
{
    ns::S s;
    sZip(s);  // OK, deduces T = ns::S
}
```

The general "best-practice" for C++ is to make function templates only if the arguments can be deduced, and to never specify the arguments explicitly. (Exceptions to this rule are `std::forward` and various `make_*` functions that require one mandatory argument for the desired result type.)

Comment: That ADL doesn't work with non-deduced arguments is, IMO, a crazy C++ oddity. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Now you got me thinking if there isn't some fundamental problem that would prevent this from being feasible... :-S For example, how does the parser know that `sBar` is a template?

Comment: Time for a new, probable-duplicate SO question!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Go for it, I've never seen anything in that direction before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953684/why-doesnt-adl-find-function-templates#comment18220679_2953783