# template object's template friend functions and namespaces

Tags: c++, templates, friend, argument-dependent-lookup

In the following C++ example code, GCC 6 and Clang 3.8 disagree on what the correct behaviour is:

This contrived example "works" -- as in the `test()` function returns `o.p` in GCC. In clang, it calls the (undefined) function `get<int, int, float, double>`:

```
template<typename ...Args>
class obj {
 bool p = false;

 template<typename T, typename... Args2>
 friend T get(const obj<Args2...> &o) { return o.p; }
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T get(const obj<Args...> &o);


bool test(const obj<int, float, double> &a) {
 return get<int>(a);
}
```

Putting the same code in a namespace causes GCC to do the same thing clang does.

```
namespace ns {

template<typename ...Args>
class obj {
 bool p = false;

 template<typename T, typename... Args2>
 friend T get(const obj<Args2...> &o) { return o.p; }
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T get(const obj<Args...> &o);

}

bool test(const ns::obj<int, float, double> &a) {
 return ns::get<int>(a);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/sWrXQO and https://godbolt.org/g/9tIXwe

Which compiler is "correct" and is there in general a way to *define* a friend member template function inline without having to declare it and then define it separately. That is, things like:

```
struct Foo {
 friend bool bar() { return true; } // declares *and* defines a free function bar
 template<typename T> T bar2() { return true; }  // doesn't work!
};
```

Comment: Why declaring `template<typename T, typename... Args>
T get(const obj<Args...> &o);` outside class ?

Comment: Because it doesn't work if you don't... try it: https://godbolt.org/g/peSscU

Comment: Yeah, `T` is non deducible, so you have to provide `<int>`, so ADL doesn't works (as there are no template `get` in global scope) :/ You may declare a dummy template get (with not correct matching) to re-enable ADL: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e40aaf90de712943).

Comment: @Jarod42 ADL should still work due to the redeclaration of `get()` in namespace scope - once unqualified lookup finds some function template, we should be able to find other function templates. I think.

Comment: @Barry: but the 2 functions would be ambiguous...

Comment: @Jarod42 There's only one function.

Comment: There's no point in defining the function template inside the class template. You'll easily get ODR violations when you instantiate different `obj` specializations: https://godbolt.org/g/RqYn9d

Comment: @T.C. interestingly, [only gcc](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1NVo2V4mSS2wjAbq), but [not clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gbaK17kbgXq2sqjk), gives ODR violation using my `force_adl` solution with different `obj` specializations:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two unresolved issues regarding `friend` function templates defined in class templates: [1545](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1545) and [2174](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2174). The former questions the extent to which it's valid at all and the latter is about odr violations that may arise based on the actual instantiations of those function templates. I am unsure which compiler is right (having previously believed that both were wrong), but it may simply be under- or poorly specified in the standard what the correct behavior is in this situation.

The code *should* ideally compile (pending issue resolution):

```
template<typename ...Args>
class obj {
 bool p = false;

 template<typename T, typename... Args2>
 friend T get(const obj<Args2...> &o) { return o.p; }
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T get(const obj<Args...> &o);
```

The `friend` declaration first declares `get`, so this creates a new member of the innermost enclosing namespace: `::get`. The external declaration just redeclares the same function, so there really is just the one `::get`. From [temp.over.link]:

> Two expressions involving template parameters are considered equivalent if two function definitions containing
>   the expressions would satisfy the one-definition rule (3.2), except that the tokens used to name the
>   template parameters may differ as long as a token used to name a template parameter in one expression is
>   replaced by another token that names the same template parameter in the other expression. For determining
>   whether two dependent names (14.6.2) are equivalent, only the name itself is considered, not the result of name lookup in the context of the template.

Using different template parameter names (`Args...` vs `Args2...`) is fine - this second declaration of the function template `::get` is valid and allows for lookup to find it.

This brings us to:

```
bool test(const obj<int, float, double> &a) {
#ifdef UNQUAL
    return get<int>(a);     // unqualified
#else
    return ::get<int>(a);   // qualified
#endif
}
```

Both of these *should* work - since we redeclared the function to be in namespace scope, we don't even have to worry about ADL. Both calls should find `::get<int>(obj<int, float, double> )`, which is a `friend`, and so the code should compile and link. gcc allows the unqualified call but not the qualified call, clang allows neither.

We could sidestep both CWG issues entirely by simply *not* defining the function template inside the class:

```
template<typename ...Args>
class obj {
 bool p = false;

 template<typename T, typename... Args2>
 friend T get(const obj<Args2...> &o);
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T get(const obj<Args...> &o) { return o.p; }
```

With this formulation, both compiles allow *both* qualified and unqualified invocation of `get`.

---

If we rewrite the code such that `obj` is a class and not a class template, but all else being equal:

```
class obj {
    bool p = false;

    template <class T>
    friend T get(const obj& o) { return o.p; }
};

template <class T> T get(const obj& );

bool test(const obj& a) {
#ifdef UNQUAL
    return get<int>(a);
#else
    return ::get<int>(a);
#endif
}
```

Both compilers allow both invocations. But there is no difference that I'm aware of in the rules between `obj` being a normal class and a class template.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply. I appreciate the workaround (of defining the get externally) - and this is what I'm already doing in my code. However the disparity between the non-templatized function being able to be defined inline (and commonly done with e.g. `friend operator<<`), and yet as soon as the function is itself templatized, having to separate its declaration and definition...is just plain confusing. But...it's C++ :)

Comment: @MattG The external template requirement can best be explained in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953684/why-doesnt-adl-find-function-templates#comment29830195_2953783). Also, I am not 100% sure that my reasoning is right about the compilers. Hoping somebody else steps in here at some point.

Comment: CWG2174 and CWG1545 might be relevant.

Comment: @T.C. Interesting that for 1545, gcc complains about redefinition but clang accepts it. I don't entirely understand 2174 or the proposed resolution.

Comment: @TemplateRex Why? I showed an example which compiles on both gcc/clang without any forward declarations.