# Undefined reference to overloaded operator in namespace

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I am writing a template class for a matrix and I want to overload its `operator*`.

Matrix.h:

```
(include guard)

namespace foo {

    template<typename T, unsigned int D>
    class Matrix {

        ...


        public:
            Matrix<T, D>& operator*=(const Matrix<T, D>& rhs) {
                (multiplication stuff)
                return *this;
            }

    };

    template<typename T, unsigned int D>
    Matrix<T, D> operator*(Matrix<T, D> lhs, const Matrix<T, D>& rhs) {
        lhs *= rhs;

        return lhs;
    }

    template class Matrix<float, 3>;

}

(include guard)
```

And then I use this class as a super class for e.g a `Matrix3x3<float>`.

But when I call `foo::Matrix3x3f m3 = m1 * m2`, where `m1` and `m2` are already initialized matrices, I get the following error message during compilation:

```
C:/Dev/Foo/main.cc:20: undefined reference to `foo::Matrix<float, 3u> operator*<float, 3u>(foo::Matrix<float, 3u>, foo::Matrix<float, 3u> const&)'
```

EDIT:

main.cc

```
#include "Matrix.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    foo::Matrix3x3<float> m1 = foo::Matrix3x3<float>::InitIdentity();
    foo::Matrix3x3<float> m2 = foo::Matrix3x3<float>::InitIdentity();

    foo::Matrix3x3<float> m3 = m1 * m2;

    return 0;
}
```

Where `InitIdentity is a static method that created an identity matrix.`

EDIT 2:

I've split the class into declaration in `Matrix.h` and definition in `Matrix.cc`. But for the template to work I did add the following at the end of both files for explicit template instantiation:

Matrix.h

```
extern template class Matrix<float, 3>;
```

Matrix.cc

```
template class Matrix<float, 3>;
```

Matrix3x3.h

```
extern template class Matrix3x3<float>;
typedef Matrix3x3<float> Matrix3x3f;
```

Matrix3x3.cc

```
template class Matrix3x3<float>;
```

As I've read here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1724632/9369168

and here

https://developer.lsst.io/cpp/style.html#b-all-templatized-classes-functions-must-be-explicitly-instantiated-i-e-the-type-declared-and-the-instances-to-be-used-explicitly-instantiated-in-the-header-file-the-type-members-are-defined-in-the-source-file

Since in know which types and sizes the matrices are going to use I thought this would be file.

Comment: Could you show your ```main.cc```?

Comment: I edited it to the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953684/why-doesnt-adl-find-function-templates  This should help. The operator* needed to be found through ADL.

Comment: *"undefined reference to"* means that definition cannot be found, are you sure you define template in header, and not in cpp?