# C++ Json Boost value to string

Tags: c++, json, boost

I have simple C++ code that uses Boost library:

```
auto jsonStringPtr = jsonValuePtr->if_string();
```

How can I convert this value to std::string without quotes?

I tested this code:

```
std::string myString = boost::json::serialize(*jsonStringPtr);
```

but it contains quotes e.g. "abc" insted of abc...
Any idea?

#edit

- Boost: v1.76.0
- C++: 20

Example:

```
boost::json::error_code errorCode;
boost::json::value jsonValue = boost::json::parse("{\"fff\": \"abc\"}", errorCode);

auto jsonString = jsonValue.as_object()["fff"].as_string();
std::string myString = boost::json::serialize(jsonString);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that require `deserialze()` or something?

Comment: Does `*jsonStringPtr` do the trick?

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution:

```
boost::json::value_to<std::string>(jsonValue)
```

Comment: Note that it's probably fine to let `ADL` find that, so you don't have to write `boost::json::value_to` but just `value_to`

Comment: Note that ADL won't work on a function call with explicit template arguments on any C++ version prior to C++20: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953684/why-doesnt-adl-find-function-templates

Answer (score 0):

```
auto jsonStringPtr = jsonValuePtr->as_string().c_str();
```